# How to remove multiple versions of Python from the Windows registry

Tags: python, windows, registry, cx-freeze

I was trying to install **cx_Freeze** module and it gives me the **could not locate network location** error along with a non existent path name(supposedly pointing to python? but it wasnt). Then I tried installing another module **py2exe**, this time the installer was a bit more user friendly and informed that I got two mentions of Python in my registry. One pointing to the correct Python directory, the other pointing to the same wrong one.

My question is how or is it possible to delete the wrong mention of Python from my registry or another way around it? I wanted to install **cx_Freeze**. Thanks

Comment: `Win + R`, `regedit`, enter, `Ctrl+F`, `python`. Searches for any mentions of python in registry (F3 to navigate to next occurence). Make sure you can tell if a path to python is valid or not.

Comment: Thank you @JOHN. I did exactly that a few secs ago

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just resolved it but not sure if this is the right way to go about it. Here's what I did,

In the cmd box, type **regedit**, and then click OK you will have the Registry editor. 
Right Clicked on the key name  **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE** and searched for the wrong path name that kept showing up. In a few seconds it will take you to the location of that path in the registry. I did see two mentions of Python. Wasn't hard to figure out the wrong one(incorrect path) and deleted it without any side effects.

Immediately after this I was able to install the modules perfectly.

Comment: In what sub folder of HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE did you find the Python entries? There are a lot of them. I found a Python folder in SOFTWARE, and several versions in the Python folder, but which do I delete, the entire version folder (2.7, 3.6, etc.) or files inside the version folders? Not sure if deleting the entire version folder will mess anything up or not.