# After uninstalling python Python is there exist registry file any?

Tags: python, windows, registry

When we uninstall any software sometimes we find some registry files in registry. Is it same to Python programming installation?

Answer (score 0):

If you use the uninstaller to uninstall Python it should clean everything up. However if you're particularly paranoid about leftover registry entries, [PEP 514](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0514/) defines where Python creates registry entries. Note that Python doesn't necessarily need to make registry entries in the first place:

> Python environments are not required to be registered unless they want to be automatically discoverable by external tools.

The system path however may still have the path to the previous python installation in it, as per this SO question [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3515673/how-to-completely-remove-python-from-a-windows-machine) [Further searching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19245329/how-to-remove-multiple-versions-of-python-from-the-windows-registry) reveals more useful information about removing Python.

Comment: If I uninstall from control panel in Windows 7 will the registry files stay in Windows registry files? Please describe details as you can.

Comment: I imagine not, that's the point of an uninstaller as opposed to just deleting it from where it is installed. Again, you can test this yourself by uninstalling it and then checking the registry locations suggested in my second link.